# how to use array as bind variable in execute immediate statement in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please find the sample code below to accept input parameter as array and create dynamic statement within stored procedure and bind using array parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_array_param(ARG_INPUT ARRAY)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    $$
    DECLARE
    res resultset;
    query varchar;
    BEGIN
    query := 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(COLUMN ::VARIANT ,?::variant)';
    res := EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query using(ARG_INPUT);
    RETURN TABLE(res);
    END;
    $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the ARRAY, it is converted to VARCHAR implicitly, this is why your query does not work. If you parse the ARRAY by yourself before binding and convert it to varchar by yourself, and then convert it to an array in your inner query, it works. Here is the demonstration:

```
create or replace table mytable (v1 varchar ) as select 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_array_param(ARG_INPUT ARRAY) RETURNS TABLE( v1 varchar ) 
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS 
$$ 
DECLARE
 res resultset; 
 temp varchar; 
 query varchar; 
BEGIN 
  temp := trim(ARG_INPUT::varchar,'[]');
  query := 'SELECT v1 from MYTABLE WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS( v1::VARIANT, split(?,'',''))'; 
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query using ( temp ) ); 
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END; 
$$;

call sp_array_param( [1,2,3,4] );
```

Comment: ,so is it better that I pass the input parameter as varchar with comma separated value instead of array ?  input parameter  'value1','value2' -->SELECT v1 from MYTABLE WHERE v1 in (  'value1','value2')

Comment: At least, ARRAY is not passed as ARRAY - so yes you can just build this statement and execute it with execute immediate.

Comment: also i was not able to run your  code  for array containing varchar values ['a','b','c']